# How do I write regular expression to match the below pattern

Tags: java, regex, substring

Pattern : (any special characters,new lines,spaces, alphabets and numbers)**[!- (any special characters,alphabets and numbers) -!]**(any special characters,new lines,spaces, alphabets and numbers)

Example :
!|this is first line|

|abc|62883HJKS,JSK|56.23|28378|**!-23838.37|63883BC|9729-!**|

Need to match all substrings like **!-23838.37|63883BC|9729-!**

Comment: https://ihateregex.io/
https://regexr.com/

Comment: Provide example of input text and output of regexp to better understand your task.

Comment: Provided sample input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could work like this

```
  final String regex = "(!-.*?-!)";
  
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex)
        .matcher(
           "|abc|6288\n3HJKS,JSK|28378|!-23838|63883BC|9729-!|abc|62883HJKS,JSK|28378|!-8XX38|638,83BC|9729-!|abc|62883HJKS,JSK|28378|!-8XX38|638\n83BC|9729-!|");

  while (m.find()) {

     System.out.println(m.group(1));
     
  }
```

Result:

1. !-23838|63883BC|9729-!
2. !-8XX38|638,83BC|9729-!

!-8XX38|638\n83BC|9729-! is ignored

instead of Regex (!-.*?-!) you could use something replacing the point like (!-[a-zA-Z0-9|,.?!]*?-!). Use *? to have lazy match to get shortest Range of !-...-!